# How many times does an on-premises Data Gateway used in multiple reports connect to the same data source?

Tags: database, powerbi, data-gateway

So, I am pretty new at using Power BI, so I'm having some issues when building reports that use on-premises Data Gateway. My goal is to build different reports in Power BI (let´s say 4 reports, as an example), all of them getting information from the same web data base. The problem is that everytime someone access this online data base, my company has to pay a small amount of money.

The reports refresh once per day, exactly at 2AM, using the on-premises Data Gateway. My point is: will the on-premises Data Gateway access this data base once per day, at 2 AM, and refresh all the reports or will it access it once for exery report (meaning 4 access at 2AM)?

If something is unclear, just warn me and I try to provide more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will follow the "4 access at 2AM" scenario.

I would design one master/dataset report that extracts all the required data from the source database.  Once published (to your workspace or a group workspace), I would use that dataset as the source for the other 3 reports.  From Power BI Desktop, go to Get Data / Power BI service.

Then you only have 1 dataset to refresh via the gateway. Another benefit is that you only have one set of queries & modelling to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
But while I was testing it, I noticed that when importing from a BI Service source, I can only connect to one source and not import from multiple data bases... But some of them need another source together with this one. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Also, besides they get data from the same source, some queries and modelling are different in each one of them

Comment: For your 1st question, in the dataset PBIX just use Get Data again to build more queries - then you can mash up queries from any source e.g. Merge and Append, or deliver separate tables into the model and build relationships.

Comment: For your 2nd question, this is trickier. Up to a point you can cater for variations, but eventually it will get too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have created the report. If the dataset is exactly the same, you should publish only one report and create the other 3 desktop files connecting to Power Bi Service as dataset. In that way you can have only one dataset for four reports and will refresh only once a day.

Regards